# How to convert textbox value to integer

Tags: c#, winforms

I have some textboxes in my C# windows form application. I want to do the following:

```
inRed = Convert.ToInt32(tbRed.Text.ToString().Length < 0 ? tbRed.Text = "0" : tbRed.Text);
inGreen = Convert.ToInt32(tbGreen.Text.ToString().Length < 0 ? tbGreen.Text = "0" : tbGreen.Text);
inBlue = Convert.ToInt32(tbBlue.Text.ToString().Length < 0 ? tbBlue.Text = "0" : tbBlue.Text);

inCyan = Convert.ToInt32(tbCyan.Text.ToString().Length < 0 ? tbCyan.Text = "0" : tbCyan.Text);
inMagenta = Convert.ToInt32(tbMagenta.Text.ToString().Length < 0 ? tbMagenta.Text = "0" : tbMagenta.Text);
```

If the textbox doesn't have a value, enter a `0` and convert to integer, otherwise convert the value of the textbox to integer.

I am getting the following error for `inCyan`, where the textbox is empty:

```
Input string was not in a correct format.
```

How can I achieve what I am looking for?

Comment: Try using `Length <= 0` instead of just `Length < 0`

Comment: Why do you add ToString to a string property?

Comment: @DavidG Wow... was missing the `=`. Thanks.

Comment: For entering numeric values you could use the [`NumericUpDown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown) control. It eliminates parsing at all.

Comment: @DavidG Or just `==` since a string can never have a negative length.

Comment: @juharr In reality I wouldn't use this method anyway as it will still generate exceptions if non numeric values are entered.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of `Convert.ToInt32`, use [`Int32.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This gives you feedback regarding if it was a valid integer. e.g.

```
String textboxValue = "1";
Int32 i;
if (!String.IsNullOrWhitespace(textboxValue) && // Not empty
    Int32.TryParse(textboxValue, out i)) { // Valid integer
  // The textbox had a valid integer. i=1
} else {
  // The texbox had a bogus value. i=default(Int32)=0
  // You can also specify a different fallback value here.
}
```

As a follow-up, [`String.IsNullOrWhitespace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) makes it easy to decipher if a value is supplied, but (depending on your .NET version) is may not be available (and you may only have [`String.IsNullOrEmpty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If need be, the polyfill is something long the lines of:

```
Boolean SringIsNullOrWhitespace(String input)
{
    return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(input) && input.Trim().Length > 0;
}
```

Also, if you find yourself trying to perform this parsing frequently, you could refactor it into a helper class:

```
public static class ConvertUtil
{
    public Int32 ToInt32(this String value)
    {
        return ToInt32(value, default(Int32));
    }
    public Int32 ToInt32(this String value, Int32 defaultValue)
    {
#if NET4
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
#else
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) && value.Trim().Length > 0)
#endif
        {
            Int32 i;
            if (Int32.TryParse(value, out i))
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return defaultValue;
    }
}

// explicit
inRed = ConvertUtil.ToInt32(tbRed.Text, 0/* defaultValue*/);
// As extension
inRed = tbRed.Text.ToInt32(0/* defaultValue*/);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like

```
// Initialise variable with 0
int value;

// Try parse it, if it's successful and able to parse then value is set to         the int equivalent of your text input
int.TryParse(inputVariable, out value);

return value
```

This is a simple way of dealing with your problem - note, if the parse fails then it returns 0 to value.

How you would apply it to your particular problem.

```
int inMagenta;
int.TryParse(tbMagenta, out inMagenta);

etc.....
```

Comment: you need to use "out" for out parameter

Answer (score 1):

You can use tryparse.

```
int inRed;  //default value will be 0 , if the string is not in a  valid form
Int32.TryParse(tbRed.Text.ToString(), out inRed);
```

Comment: Just adding some information for the OP, `TryParse` will return the value `0` if the conversion is unsuccessful. [More info here on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: No, `TryParse` returns a bool. Correct way to check would be `if(TryParse(...))`.

Comment: @DionV. yes it gives both the Int output in out parameter and the conversion status in boolean.